# Is asking questions about Islam kufr?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, kufr

I’m just wondering about this ruling on asking questions about Islam. Some say it’s discouraged and some say it’s haram but my question is would it be considered kufr if you ask too many questions about Islam. So in my case I asked “it doesn’t make sense, why does Prophet Muhammad love us more than our mother loves us if he didn’t meet us in the first place?”

Edit: is my question in quotations considered doubt

Comment: The "it doesn't make sense" part is a statement not a question. It is clear disbelief. The question itself doesn't  need to be if you are asking genuinely for explanation while not disbelieving.

Comment: First the statement I know of is about Allah's love not the prophet's love. Any person asks for a reason if this reason is for example  to get knowledge why shouldn't that be perfectly halal?

Comment: can you give me the reference for what you said?, "Prophet Muhammad loves us more than our mother". i don't think there is any hadith like that

Comment: Sorry if I caused any confusion i don’t know the exact Hadith that said so but I remember reading is somewhere but my memory is foggy. And when I was asking the question I had no intention of disbelief rather an explanation. So when I said it doesn’t make sense I didn’t actually mean that Islam doesn’t make sense rather I was just confused and wanted an answer. So if I had no intention of disbelief would I be a kufr? I’m really worried I hadn’t thought this through when i asked this question and now I fear might’ve committed kufr

Comment: @Abdulrahman Your quotation is wrong i think. It should Allah Instead of prophet Muhammad SAW that you mentioned. However Asking question is not kufr. But asking question without having the basic knowledge or without researching yourself first is not appropriate and allah might not like that, what i meant is, sometimes people ask questions without reading Quran even once or they ask Islamic question, without doing absolutely no research on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the word of the prophet (saw) does not refer to himself but to Allah for whom He speaks. The love of the mother or the father or any loving person is part of the love of the Eternal and thus logically less than the whole.

Answer (score 0):

The questions should be unbiased and should not have any sort of grudge but they should be to clear our thoughts and concepts.

“The word of wisdom is the lost property of the believer. Wherever he finds it, he is most deserving of it.” (Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2687)

How you get wisdom and knowledge? Off course by questioning, reading, listening people more wiser than us etc.. So ask questions but to grab wisdom and knowledge as you can in your life not to show the grudge. Its the teachings of our Prophet PBUH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand one thing my brother; that the Rasool (saw) is infallible. Therefore, if he says he loves us more then he does. When a statement comes from the Rasool (saw), don't try reasoning it.

As for asking questions, don't ask questions you can't, or any other man can't comprehend. Like how does Allah sit etc? You can't ever comprehend that because you, or any other person can't sense (see) Allah (swt). Hence, since you can't meet the Messenger (saw) to tell you why is it that he loves us more than our mothers, then you must trust his statement as long as it is authentically reported.

Allah (swt) knows best